# How to call a contract method with tron-web

Tags: javascript, web3js, tron, tronweb

I'm trying to call a simple contract method that just returns a string of data. I've based my code on the example that can be found in the docs => https://developers.tron.network/reference#methodcall

```
tronWeb.trx.getContract("TFWbGYFVjUMKrHALdU4MnFWNYY9Uc5W9SZ").then(async contract => {
    console.log(contract);
    let abi = contract.abi;
    console.log(abi);
    let c = await tronWeb.contract({
        abi
    });
    let result = await c.getBadgeOwner('something is up').call();
    console.log(result);
});
```

The difference with what can be found in the docs, is that I'm loading the abi from my loaded contract, instead of hard coding it like in the example.

The error I get is `index.js:105 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.forEach is not a function` which seems to refer to the abi somehow:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

For anyone tripping over the same beginner mistake, here's how to solve it:

Use contract().at() instead of getContract()

```
let contract = await tronWeb
        .contract()
        .at("TFWbGYFVjUMKrHALdU4MnFWNYY9Uc5W9SZ")
```

After that, you can call your contract methods just fine

```
let currentValue = await contract.getBadgeOwner('something is up').call();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(async () => {
   this.myContractOb = await 
   this.tronWeb.contract(myContract).at(this.contractAddress);
},10000);
```

Using above code with myContract as ABI json object having same issue.

Answer (score -1):

I was doing the same mistake before. This works for me

```
async function a (){
        let contract = await tronWeb.contract().at("TFWbGYFVjUMKrHALdU4MnFWNYY9Uc5W9SZ")
        //console.log(contract);
        let currentValue = await contract.getBadgeOwner('something is up').call();
        console.log(currentValue);
}

a()
```